# Prime Factorization of Large Numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Recently, I have been required to compute the Prime Factorization of large numbers.

For instance,

$5^9 -1 $

I know that it ends in a $4$, so can be divided by $2$. Then can be divided by $2$ again, but this creates a factor tree which is what I am looking to avoid.

How would I go about prime factorising this?

---

By my factor tree method I get to $2\times 2\times 19\times 31\times 829$. But I had to type into the internet whether $829$ was a prime, so I immediately run into a problem.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, the question of "how to factor large numbers" is an incredibly broad and difficult question, although it's quite fast to do with a computer for small numbers. You might want to start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) or with a book on elementary number theory or cryptography, but I think this question is too broad.

Comment: It's not that difficult to check whether $829$ is prime by hand. $\sqrt{829}<30$, so you only need to check the primes up to $30$. It seems a lot harder to find the prime factors of $\frac{5^9-1}{2^2}$ by hand

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov This is the problem. This could come up in an exam where I am only equipped with a calculator. I am thinking there must be a simple way to do it and I am overlooking it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is called **prime factorization** (Yes, that is in the title).

In order to determine if $829$ is a prime number or not, I would use trial division:

> If the number $829$ is not divisible by any prime number that is less that $\sqrt{829}$ than the number $829$ is prime.

By using your factor tree method, you have factored it to $2\times 2\times 19\times 31\times 829$.

At this point, if you are doing it right (test the divisibility of $5^9-1$ starting from the smallest prime number, which is $2$), then the number $829$ is not divisible by any prime numbers from $2$ to $31$. Because $31^2=961>829$, that is enough to show that $829$ is a prime number.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the prime number check :) I have a follow up question - The question has been written as $ 5^9 -1 $ for a reason, so what method would you use the solve this question?

Comment: Using a calculator: $(5^9-1)\div 2=976562$ (I would recommend to write those number down in a rough paper); $976562\div 2=488281$, no longer divisible by $2$, check $3$; $488281\div 3$ will not yield an integer result... Continue for $5;7;11;13;17;19$ and you will see that dividing by $19$ now yields an integer result (that number is not too big for a $10$-digit calculator).

Comment: To reduce the number of calculator steps: Note that a natural number is divisible by $2$ if and only if the last digit is even. A number is divisible by $3$ if and only if the sum of all digits is divisible by $3$. A number is divisible by $5$ if and only if the last digit is $0$ or $5$.

Answer (score 1):

no truly simple way. You have
$$ x^9 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)(x^6 + x^3 + 1) $$
As the third factor is also of the form $u^2 + u + 1,$ it can only be divisible by primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \; ,$ more specifically $p \equiv 7 \pmod 6 \; .$ Once you get to $15751$ and find that it is not divisible by $7,13,$ you get a bit of luck with $19.$ The leftover is $829.$ It is not divisible by $19$ or $31,$ and that is it. You have exceeded $\sqrt {829} \approx 28.7$ so $829$ is prime.

In case of interest, this has to do with quadratic residues.

Comment: How did you know that was the factorisation? Did you use the roots of unity?